# using async await function in mocha assertion with supertest

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to write tests for my Node API with `Mocha` and `Supertest`.

I had success using promises with `.then`, but that quickly turned into "callback" hell which is difficult to maintain long term.

```
// Success using `.then`
describe('/categories', () => {
  it('GET-/categories ,should contain 2 category documents after creating', done => {
    request(app)
      .post('/categories')
      .send({
        name: 'user1',
      })
      .then(res => {
        request(app)
          .post('/categories')
          .send({
            name: 'user2',
          })
          .then(res => {
            request(app)
              .get('/categories')
              .then(res => {
                const categories = res.body;
                expect(categories.length).to.equal(2);
                done();
              });
          });
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });
});
```

Now I'm trying to write it with `async` `await`, but it returns an error.

```
// DOES NOT WORK using `async`/`await`
describe('/categories', () => {
  it('GET-/categories ,should contain 2 category documents after creating', async done => {
    try {

      const category1 = await request(app)
        .post('/categories')
        .send({
          name: 'user2',
        });

      const category2 = await request(app)
        .post('/categories')
        .send({
          name: 'user2',
        });

      const categories = await request(app).get('/categories');
      const result = categories.body;
      expect(result.length).to.equal(2);
      done();

    } catch (e) {
      done(e);
    }
  });
});
```

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or*
>   return a Promise; not both.

While researching this issue, I saw some threads that recommended omitting `done()`, so I did, but the test did not work properly. They even failed asserts get a pass.

```
// DOES NOT WORK using `async`/`await` without `done()`
describe('/categories', () => {
  it('GET-/categories ,should contain 2 category documents after creating', async () => {
    try {

      const category1 = await request(app)
        .post('/categories')
        .send({
          name: 'user2',
        });

      const category2 = await request(app)
        .post('/categories')
        .send({
          name: 'user2',
        });

      const categories = await request(app).get('/categories');
      const result = categories.body;
      expect(result.length).to.equal(2);

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this help at all? https://techsparx.com/nodejs/async/async-mocha-rest-tests.html

Comment: thx for shareing actally i removed that try-catch block it was catching errors not letting assertions to work as they should

Comment: Nice. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , i find the answer first of all you should not pass a done() callback function using async and then using try-catch block statement interfere with assertion and doent not let the test work naturally . you probably better not to put your assertions in a catch-try statement!

```
it('GET-/categories ,should contain 2 category documents after creating',async()=>{
            const category1 = await  
            request(app).post('/categories')
            .send({
                name       :'user1'
            }); 
            const category2 = await
            request(app).post('/categories')
            .send({
            name       :'user2'
            })

            const result =await 
            request(app).get('/categories')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Acccept', 'application/json')
            .catch(err => { 
                throw err; 
            })
            const categories= result.body;
            expect(categories.length).to.equal(2);

    })
```